# Tuning a 12 string guitar

Tags: guitar, tuning

I recently acquired a 12 string guitar.  What kind of strings should I get so the octave higher strings won't break?  My electronic tuner is made for a 6 string guitar.  Is there a special guitar tuner for a 12 string guitar?

Comment: The higher octave strings are thinner, to retain about the same tension as the original six. Recommendations are out of the scope of this site.